# Figma SVG not parsing with flutter_svg

Tags: flutter, svg, vector, figma

I have created a bunch of vector graphics I want to use inside my flutter application but cannot seem to load any SVGs from `Figma` using `flutter_svg`.

This is the error I'm receiving

```dart
The following assertion was thrown while parsing AssetBundlePictureKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#e7c1f(), name: "assets/images/question-btn.svg", colorFilter: null, theme: SvgTheme(currentColor: null, fontSize: 14.0, xHeight: 7.0)) in _getDefinitionPaint:
Failed to find definition for url(#Group 1__d)

This library only supports <defs> and xlink:href references that are defined ahead of their references.
```

I understand the issue and why it's occurring but is there a way to export a component in figma to an svg that'll work in flutter.

Comment: I think your svg code is not yet properly formatted for flutter_svg to process.

Comment: It would be interesting to see the SVG code, but in any case something is referencing something here. Maybe that something could be rearranged in Figma or the export could be "standalone" (I don't know if that is a thing).

Comment: Maybe you could check this article and plugin: https://medium.com/mabiloft/we-designed-an-icon-font-with-figma-and-fontello-and-it-has-not-been-a-piece-of-cake-b2948973738e & https://www.figma.com/community/plugin/771155994770327940/Fill-Rule-Editor and

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears, from the error message, that your SVG has `id` attributes that have spaces in them.

```
url(#Group 1__d)
```

The part after the `#` has to be the `id` of another element.  But `id` values cannot have spaces in them.

I would expect Figma to handle that gracefully when exporting an SVG. But perhaps it doesn't.

Try editing your Figma file and remove the spaces from your layer names.  For example, change `Group 1__d` to something like `Group_1__d`, or `Group1d`, etc.